# How to tune layout for a particular page/post in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to  make some changes in Jekyll's layout. Changes are small and different. For example, linking an additional CSS or JavaScript file. Or adding some info in header. Or tuning page title.
*Important* that these changes depend on a page/post.

Since changes are small and diverse, creating a special layout for each of them seems to be too expensive.

I tried to create my own solution but run into [impossibility to use variables in including instructions](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/176).

Has anyone solved something similar? For example, linking a special CSS to a particular post?

Comment: BTW, till [1.3.0](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#130__20131104) version of Jekyll it is now possible to use variables in includes — `{% include {{variable}} %}` :)

Answer (score 40):

You can use [YAML front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) to tune anything you want for any post/page. Any info you provide there would be accessible through in layouts and includes under `page` variable or under specific post in any list of them.

This sounds like a solution for your case: you could use YAML front matter like this:

```
---
extra_css:
  - foo.css
  - dir/bar.css
  - /s/baz.css
---
```

And then use this in your layout's header like this:

```
{% for css_name in page.extra_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ css_name }}">
{% endfor %}
```

In such way you could add any logic based on what data you provide with a post in YAML front matter.

If you'd like to abstract some of those logic to modules, you can use a hack around the includes, assigning a variable before that include and then using it inside. [Here is a link](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/bootstrap-api.html) with a description how it's made in Jekyll Bootstrap project (btw, the site for it have a lot of nice info on Jekyll).

And, yes, Jekyll don't allow the use of variables in includes, so if you'd like to include something conditionally, you would need a list of all available includes somewhere and then create all the conditions for inserting one or another when you'll need them.

---

Another solution is to divide everything in layout to includes, and make layouts with different levels of complexity — this way you could set any of those basic layouts for post and then write any extra code with includes of any blocks you'll need from the basic layouts, so you post could look like this:

```
---
layout: custom
---
<aside class="sidebar">
    {% include comments.html %}
    {% include sidebar.html %}
</aside>
<div class="content" role="main">
    Foo bar baz
</div>
```

There you could use a custom layout that don't include a basic layout for page and don't include the sidebar and comments, so you could per-post decide what level of layout you want and then redefine anything that needed to be redefined.

Also, if you'll need to tweak different places but with an unknown content, you could use YAML front matter with blocks, like

```
extra_head: |
    <style>
    * {background: red}
    </style>
```

then you could call such variable from head: `{{ page.extra_head }}` and get any content you placed there. However, you can't use any liquid tags inside YAML, but you could then use any YAML tags on such variables, so you could markdownify them or replace any strings inside with anything else by simple replace filter.

And if nothing of those fit you, then Jekyll won't fit you — as I wrote in a comment, Jekyll is just a blog engine and you shouldn't wait it to be complex as XSLT.

Comment: Linking an additional CSS is just an example. As I've said, there are many changes and they are diverse. I cannot predict them to take into account in templates. But I'd like any post/page to be able to change it's layout a bit.

Comment: Well, your need then is out of scope for Jekyll, if you cannot predict which places to change or can't add the needed logic to the layouts for new posts, then Jekyll won't fit you — it's just a convenient static blog engine that can be expanded _a bit_. And what you need is a complex configurable solution. However, I doubt that there are any that would be at the same time as much as good as Jekyll is for blogging. So, if you need both, I'll recommend forget about tuning layout by tuning the post alone and make appropriate changes to layouts each time you need something different.

Comment: There is a way to deal with inline js or css?

Answer (score 0):

I have ever tried to create an independent page in the jekyll-bootstrap static site. For example `my_cv.html` which needs independent css style. Instead of create a new github repository with gh-pages (sorry GitHub), I just simply fill all the final html contents into the a post `my_cv.md` since `markdown` format is actually compatible with `html` I think, and luckily it works.